# How to download data and show in LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, longlistselector

I am working on a news reader. I get a collection of data in JSON format and I want to show it in a `LongListSelector`.

I faced two problems:

I convert the JSON data to a class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string Username;
    public int Id;
    public string Permalink;
    public string Uri;
    public string Permalink_url;
    public string Avatar_url;
    // .. many more

    //Empty Constructor
    public User() { }
}
```

Then should I convert this class to a `ViewModel` to show it in `LongListSelector` with binding? *(how?)* or there is a better way?

we use a view model like this, so `LongListSelector` notifies when something changes. should I write like this for all of the above properties one by one?

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _lineOne;
    public string LineOne
    {
        get
        {
            return _lineOne;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _lineOne)
            {
                _lineOne = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LineOne");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

anyway, what is the best simple clean approach for getting json data and representing it in a `LongListSelector` and add more items if needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say for eg. you bind your LongListSelector's ItemsSource with the ObservableCollection called items.

```
<LongListSelector Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
  .....
</LongListSelector>
```

Now, you need data to populate this list.User class will perform this task for you.
Use Newtonsoft.Json library to get the JObject obj from json data.

Then call the User class parameterized constructor on the screen where you want to display the data.

```
User userObject = new User(obj);
list.DataContext = new ViewModel(userObject);
```

Define this constructor in User class as below:

```
public User(JObject obj)
{
   this.UserName = (string)obj["UserName"];
   .....
   ....
}
```

Now you have the UserObject which contains all the data needed to populate the LongListSelector. Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your class if you want some data to be changed later.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ObservableCollection<UserDetail> items = new ObservableCollection<UserDetail>();
   .....
   .....
   public ViewModel(User u)
   {
     UserDetail ud = new UserDetail(u);
     //assign your data to this view class here and finally add it to the collection
     .....
     .....

     items.Add(ud);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a UserViewModel that takes the User DTO as parameter in its constructor and wraps it. I would then create an

```
ObservableCollection<UserViewModel> Users {get; set;} //use INotifyPropertyChanged
```

property in my page ViewModel and bind this property to the LongListSelector's ItemSource property like so

```
<LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"/>
```

If you decide that you want to automatically load more items when the User scrolls to the end you can use the ItemRealized event of the LongListSelector to ask your page ViewModel to load more items.